# Laravel 5.4 sometimes validation rules not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-5.4

I am trying to validate a date field only if it is present. It was working fine before I upgraded from Laravel 5.2 to 5.4

In Laravel 5.2 this rules works fine:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'available_from' => 'date',
    ];

}
```

In 5.4 it returns validation error `The available from is not a valid date.` I tried this new rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'available_from' => 'sometimes|date',
    ];

}
```

Still got the same error and seems the `sometimes` rules not affecting the validation at all. How can I get rid of this error?

I don't understand why Laravel changed something that was working before!!!

Comment: What is the format you are using for date?

Comment: I use this format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem occurs because of \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class in Http\Kernel.php.

When you submit empty date field this middleware converts empty string to null. Then validation returns not valid date error. You can check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields) for more details.

It can be fixed with **nullable**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'available_from' => 'sometimes|nullable|date',
    ];

}
```

From [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-nullable):

> nullable
>
> The field under validation may be null. This is particularly useful
>   when validating primitive such as strings and integers that can
>   contain null values.

Comment: Wonderful help. Work perfectly in Laravel 5.6 also.

Comment: I'm getting the same "is not a valid date" and I'm always sending dates like "2018-03-05" through Postman

Comment: You just literally saved my day.